# How to pass a state (hook) between separated files (components) in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Btw I already did a lot of research trying to solve this; So far I'm still stuck on this:

This is the first component in `file1.jsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function MenuPopupState(props){
    const [career, setCareer] = React.useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => { setCareer(career) }}>
                Press me
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is the another component in `file2.jsx` where I want to use the `career` state:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuPopupState from './components/Menupopup';

export default function Header(){
    const career = MenuPopupState.career;

    return (
        <div>
            <a key={career.id}>
                {career.name}
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried differents methods, without reaching my goal of use the career.name in the Header

Comment: you need to use global state management like redux to be able to share data between components

Comment: @nassimmiled that is absolutely untrue. There are many ways to trickle state down to various branches of your tree, redux and global state management libraries are just one of those ways. And they should not be the _first_ one you try when something far simpler will do fine.

Comment: @AlexWayne that's true, but he didn't mention that they are related, in many cases, you can't elevate state to the parent component so you must use a global state management

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If state is shared between components, then you need to elevate that state to a common parent.

Then you can pass that state down to the children, probably as [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

For example:

```
function App() {
    const [career, setCareer] = React.useState('');

    return <>
        <MenuPopupState career={career} onClick={setCareer} />
        <Header career={career} />
    </>
}

function MenuPopupState(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.career)}>
                Press me
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

function Header(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <a key={props.career.id}>
                {props.career.name}
            </a>
        </div>
    )
}
```